# How to Add a Where Not Equals condition in Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview, casting

I use this code to `cast` my `DataGridView` and then display results in another `DataGridView`.

Basically, I'm getting some int values and calculating their sum, while also grouping these values with `GroupBy`.

I display the results in another `DataGridView` like so:

```
datagridview2.DataSource= Su.ToList();
```

My problem is that the query seems to stop if the cell has a string value.

I've tried adding a '`where` not' condition to exclude rows  that contain string values in several different ways but did not succeed.

Here an example of the condition I've tried:

```
.Where(row => !row.Cells[2].Value.ToString().Equals("example"))
```

This code is in the `datagridview_cellvaluechanged` method:

```
    try
{
    var Su = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Where(row => row.Cells[8].Value != null)
    .Where(row => row.Cells[2].Value != null)
    .GroupBy(row => row.Cells[8].Value.ToString()) 
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Gruppo = g.Key,
        Serie = g.Sum(row => Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Value)),
        Reps = g.Sum(row => Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[3].Value) * Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Value)),
        Percent = (g.Sum(row => Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[2].Value)) / Convert.ToDecimal(label15.Text)) * 100
    });
}
catch (FormatException)
{
    //MessageBox.Show("Formato non corretto");
}
```

This is what the DataGridView should look like, if it suceeds; dgv1:

```
column 1 | column 2 |column 3
  2          3        group1
  3          5        group1
  4          6        group2
  3          4        group3
```

And I see this in the result on dgv2:

```
    column 1 | column 2 |column 3
      5          8        group1
      4          6        group2
      3          4        group3
```

But if I add a string value in column2 like this:

```
column 1 | column 2 |column 3
  2          3        group1
  3          5        group1
  4        string     group2
  3          4        group3
```

Then I see this in the result on dgv2:

```
column 1 | column 2 |column 3
  5          8        group1
```

Comment: What do you mean by "then the query stops"?

Comment: @faso I mean that the cast stops at the row where found a string. So for example, If in the datagridview1 I have 5 rows and there is a string in the row 4, the cast stop on that row. Even if I change some values previous or after that row (that have string value), I don't see any change in the dgv where I display the result

Comment: Convert.ToInt32 is not going to be happy if you have a value for Cells[2].value that cannot be converted to an integer. I guess that is why you're trying to validate Cells[2].value. If you're looking for anything that can be converted to an integer, you could try (row => int.TryParse(row.Cells[2].Value, out _)) which should select all rows that can convert to an integer

Comment: @MarkRabjohn I edited the question to explain better. I tried your suggest but I get this error: "not possible to convert from object to string". Where I must put it?

Comment: you have to first decide what should happen when an invalid value is provided. Should it just stop? Should it ignore the whole row?

Comment: @AsPas In this moment the query just stop. Would be fine if I can ignore it or assign a specific int value

Comment: It probably stops because it throws an exception. Since your catch block is empty, nothing happens. Why are you using specific cells like `row.Cell[8]`? You are casting the dgv to a collection of rows and then grouping them by a specific cell, then you are doing calculations on specific cells of that row and transforming them into an anonymous object? Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @AsPas yes, it's correct. The dgv is for create gym workouts. I use row.Cell[8] because it contains the group name of trained muscles. Then the query calculate the workout parameters like series, reps, percent of any muscle trained. I've tried also without the try/catch and I get no errors. The query only stop.

Comment: @Gabriele try the approach is explained in my answer, I haven't tested it so you might need to tweak a few things, but that how I would go about it

Comment: @Gabriele - Lots of responses here but my original suggestion would be used in the .Where, like .Where(row => int.TryParse(row.Cells[2].Value, out _)) - so only rows that have a Cell[2] that casts to Int can pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm still not *entirely* sure what the issue is, I will attempt to answer your question.

First off, if you are not 100% sure that a specific cell contains an Int value, you should not just blindly convert it.

There are ways to check if it is an int before converting it. One way is this:

```
    try
{
    var Su = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Where(row => row.Cells[8].Value != null)
    .Where(row => row.Cells[2].Value != null)
    .GroupBy(row => row.Cells[8].Value.ToString()) 
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Gruppo = g.Key,
        Serie = g.Sum(row => {
            if(row.Cells[2].Value is int rowInteger)
                return rowInteger;

            // if it is not an integer then try to convert
            // return a default value (in this case -1) if it can't be converted
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    return Convert.ToInt32(row)
                }
                catch(Exception)
                {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        },
        Reps = g.Sum(row => Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[3].Value) * Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Value)),
        Percent = (g.Sum(row => Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[2].Value)) / Convert.ToDecimal(label15.Text)) * 100
    });
}
catch (FormatException)
{
    //MessageBox.Show("Formato non corretto");
}
```

This will make sure that all rows are kept but only the rows that are valid are calculated on.

A simpler approach, that won't keep the original number of rows is to check whether the value of the cell is an int or can be converted into an int is to add the following `Where` statement:

```
Where(row => row.Cells[2].Value is int || int.TryParse((row.Cells[2].Value as string), out var result))
```

Note that you are actually parsing the value in each iteration and discarding the result, this is of course far from being optimized but will get you the wished result.

Comment: The second example give me this error: "is not possible to convert from 'object' to 'string' and if I add ToString after row.Cells[2].Value I don't see error but the query is not working (it stop like before). I'm not sure where to add the code of the first example. It end with " if(var " ?

Comment: swap your `Serie = g.Sum`  function with the first example.

Comment: @Gabriele I edited my answer to show where it needs to go. I changed the seconde example to cast the object into a string as well. You can try the second example again.

Comment: Perfect! now It works fine!! Thank You very much!